# Как вывести на экран все символы из списка

Tags: python, list

Как вывести на экран все символы из списка:

```
first_lis = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],[True,False,['w',2,2.3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться рекурсией.

```py
def print_all(lst: list):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        value = lst[i]
        if type(value) == list:
            print_all(value)
        else:
            print(value)
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: `for i in range(len(lst)):` -> `for value in lst:`, тогда `value = lst[i]` не нужно

Comment: А это для питона 3.Во втором по моему будет именно через len

Answer (score 0):

```
first_lis = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],[True,False,['w',2,2.3]]]

def list_pull(L):
    return sum([list_pull(i) if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in L], [])

print(*list_pull(first_lis))
```

результат:

```
1 2 3 a b c True False w 2 2.3
```